# Typo3 6.2 image caption with link

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, typo3, typoscript, caption, typo3-6.2.x

I'm trying to make the image captions to link to the image link on Typo3 6.2.

I already tried this but no lucky:

```
tt_content.image.20.caption.1.stdWrap.typolink.parameter.field = image_link
```

I have this typoscript from Bootstrap Package:

```
...
    singleCaption {
        singleStdWrap {
            wrap {
                override.cObject = COA
                override.cObject {
                    10 = TEXT
                    10 {
                        value = <figure class="image###CLASSES###">|###CAPTION###</figure>
                        override = <figure class="thumbnail###CLASSES###">|###CAPTION###</figure>
                        override {
                            if {
                                value = 1
                                equals.field = imageborder
                            }
                        }                            
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        caption {
            wrap = <caption class="caption###CLASSES###"> | </caption>
            wrap.override = <figcaption class="caption###CLASSES###"> | </figcaption>
        }
    }
 ...
```

How can I make my captions linkable to the image link? This should be so simple but I can't figure it out how. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 6):

Try this, It will probably do it:

```
tt_content.image.20.caption.1.stdWrap.typolink.parameter.data = file:current:link
```

Answer (score 1):

another way is to enable linking on captions generally:

---

### Image Captions linked (generally, if no link has been defined, the image source will be taken)

```
tt_content.image.20.caption.1.stdWrap.typolink < tt_content.image.20.1.imageLinkWrap.typolink
```

---

### Image Captions linked (only if caption link has been set)

```
tt_content.image.20.caption.1.stdWrap.typolink.parameter.data = file:current:link
```

-->  thx to Ravi Dhoriya ツ

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like:

`... .singleCaption.caption.stdWrap.typolink.parameter.field = image_link`

As you are "manually" rendering your content with the TS from the bootstrap package, I think you should apply the additional TypoScript there, not in the tt_content TS from css_styled_content.

Comment: Hi Urs, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I tried but no lucky. Do you have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Simply try to remove the `trim = 1` from `stdWrap`.

```
tt_content.image.20.caption.1.1.trim >
```

That means also that you must not have any newlines in your caption.